# How to perform an HttpClient Get request on the server using Angular 17 SSR?

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, angular-ssr

I'm currently using SSR in combination with Angular for the first time. I created a basic application with routing and one of my components that can be navigated to does an `HttpClient.get` request.

**When navigating to my component using UI buttons**

It seems like the SSR server does not wait for the get request to be finalized before the renderd component is send to the frontend when I navigate to the correct component in the frontend. Because I surrounded the get request with an if check on platform server, no data is shown at all.
[image]

**When refreshing the app on the correct route path**

However, when I navigate to the correct route path and refresh my browser the SSR server does send a rendered component WITH data to the frontend. The `<li>` data originates from the get request:
[image]

My question is, how does server side rendering the components work? How and when are such async http calls executed and waited for?

**UPDATE**
I tried using

```
    private fetchData(): void {
        this.http
            .get<Todo[]>('https://basss.free.beeceptor.com/todos')
            .pipe(tap(t => console.log(t)))
            .subscribe(todos => {
                this.todos = todos;
            });
    }
```

And using

```
    private fetchData(): void {
        if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
            this.http
                .get<Todo[]>('https://basss.free.beeceptor.com/todos')
                .pipe(tap(t => console.log(t)))
                .subscribe(todos => {
                    this.todos = todos;
                    this.transferState.set(this.myKey, todos);
                });
        } else if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
            this.todos = this.transferState.get(this.myKey, []);
        }
    }
```

Both of these solutions are only working when the component containing this code is the initially loaded route. It does simply not work when I navigate towards this component using my frontend. (the route is lazy loaded)

Comment: Consider sharing your code that contains the GET request.

Comment: @John, please see the update in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I replicated your app as much as possible and it just works. Check out [my version on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/%7E/github.com/johnnygerard/so-77698569). If the link does not work (the StackBlitz "Open a GitHub repository" feature is still in beta), you can check out [my GitHub repository](https://github.com/johnnygerard/so-77698569) instead.

Be aware that Beeceptor has a limit of 50 requests per day and per endpoint (see [pricing](https://beeceptor.com/pricing/)). Once you reach this limit, you will get a 429 (Too Many Requests) HTTP response.

So, my advice is that you check for this limit first. Otherwise, compare your code with mine. I don't think your issue has anything to do with SSR. It could be a routing configuration issue. Check out `src/app/app.routes.ts` for routes and `src/app/app.config.ts` for providers.

Another possibility is that your development server (Vite) had an issue. Stop it, then run `ng cache clean` and restart it with `ng serve`.

Consider configuring the `HTTPClient` provider with `withFetch`. See [`provideHttpClient`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/provideHttpClient#description) for more information.

**UPDATE**
So, if I understand what you were really asking, you want to fetch the data from the mock API on the SSR server instead of client-side. But why? Even if you achieve this, think about the consequences. Since the fetch request is asynchronous, it will not only delay the response from the SSR server (increasing TTFB) but it will also increase the total size of the HTTP response.
One the main reasons to use SSR is improve perceived load time.

Check out [Rendering on the Web](https://web.dev/articles/rendering-on-the-web) to learn more about SSR.

Comment: Thank you for your effort! Your example indeed works as expected, since the frontend also executes the http get request. If you observe the sources being pulled from the server, they never contain any filled `li` elements. Could you wrap the fetch data with the `isPlatformServer` check and introduce the `transferState` (as per my second code example)?
In that scenario I expect the server to execute the http get request and provide the fetched data to the frontend. As I describe in my question/issue statement that only happens why I refresh my page at `localhost/two/four`, not when I navigate.

Comment: It looks like the lazy loaded `FourComponent` is not server side rendered when I navigate towards this component via the frontend buttons, only when it is the initially loaded route.

UPDATE: i'm aware of the beeceptor limits, and I already have `withFetch` configured as per your link.

Comment: I'm not sure what your goal is. I thought you had a problem with your app. The fact that `li` elements are not filled with data by the SSR server is normal. When you request component four, you get the rendered template which initially has no data. Then, the `HTTPClient` requests the data from the Mock API.

Comment: As far as I know it should be possible to to add the `isPlatformServer` check around the fetching so that the fetching happens on the server, not client. Using the `transferState` I should then be able to provide that data to the client. This works partly, as previously described, only when component four is the initially loaded route.

Comment: The fact that what I describe in my previous comment works perfect when I directly navigate towards `localhost/two/four` (data retrieved by server, not client) makes me think it's not such a weird use case. That is why I wonder why it does not work when I navigate towards the route.